# What does "string":controller.text mean in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

What does string followed by : and then controller.text do in a list?
So for instance, if we consider the code below (please note songname is TextEditingController and has been wired as a controller, i.e controller : songname ).

```
void finalUpload(){
  var data={
    "song_name":songname.text,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
var data={
    "song_name":songname.text,
  };
```

is a [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Map-class.html), a map contains a key in this case its `song_name` and a value which is `songname.text`.

You can then access the value by using the `key`:

```
  print(data["song_name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a Map<K,V>. It's a collection of keys and values, in this case the key is the string "song_name" and its value is songname.text (which is also a String), so this is a Map<String,String>

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Map-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also open your songtext like this:

```
void getSongtext() {
  print(data[data.keys.elementAt(0)]);
}
```

You just need a triggerpoint like a button.